# Strange outputs char in C (This is not typo)

Tags: c, char, output, printf, string-literals

Please explain what is going on. I am unable to make sense of the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c="c";
    printf("%c",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Also what will be the output when `c="false"`, `"e"`,'false' etc

I wish to understand whats going on. I know that char are to be used like: 'a'.

PS The code runs perfectly fine and was asked in my undergraduate course exam for Progamming Introduction.

Comment: Character constants are written in single quotes. You should get a warning from the compiler on this code.

Comment: You will get compilation error because `c` is not declared.

Comment: @MikeCAT That's  my fault. Edited

Comment: `"c"` --> `'c'`  Double-quotes are for strings. Single-quotes for chars.

Comment: C doesn't have a string class. The string class which C doesn't have is not `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
char c = "c"
```

is wrong, `"c"` is an array which contains one element and a null termination, the first element is 99, also called `'c'`. For eg.

```
char ab[2] = "ab"
```

Here, `"ab"` is equivalent to `{'a', 'b', '\0'}` The '\0' at the end is explained below. `"c"` is equivalent to `{'c', '\0'}` and arrays generally point to the first element of the array. So, in your code `c` actually points to an array, whose first element is `c`. So the pointer to that array also points to 'c'.

```
char c = *"c"
```

actually works but is bad. You could also change the `printf` to `printf("%c\n", *c)` if `c` were a pointer, deferencing `c` will give you the first element of the array and `c` is the first and element.

You should do

```
char c = 'c'
```

And the null termination of strings is because:

`"c"` or any other string is actually `{'c', '\0'}` with a null termination at the end. It's need so that we can know when a string ends. For eg.

In `"abcdefgh"`, we would have no idea when the string ended, the user would have to know how long each string is plus how long the buffer is, so it is terminated by a `'\0'` at he end and the string is stopped to be parsed when `'\0'` is reached.
So, `"abcdefgh"` is actually `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '\0'}`.

Comment: `"c"` is an array that contains *two* elements and is not equivalent to `{'c'}`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just realized I forgot to say that I have not counted the null termination and I was editing my answers when you commented this. I'm just surprised at how fast people comment.

Comment: Will happily revert my vote once fixed.

Comment: You cannot do `printf("%c\n", *c)` with `char c`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Am I missing anything else, I really think I am given how many mistakes I already have.

Comment: @MikeCAT I just assumed everyone would just use logic to figure out that `c` would be a pointer. Made that clear as well.

Comment: The first part still contains wrong claims which I pointed to. You have added second part which is correct, but it is conflicting with what you said in the first one. Better fix the first part. I will revert my vote note trusting it will be fixed

Comment: @EugeneSh. Now, have I messed up anything?

Answer (score 0):

To assign a single character value to a `char` object, use single quotes:

```
char c = 'c';
```

Double quotes signify a *string*, which is a sequence of characters including a zero-valued terminator - the string `"c"` is actually the sequence `{'c', 0}` and its type is "2-element array of `char`", which in this instance "decays" to type "pointer to `char`".

Handy mnemonic - single characters use single quotes.

**EDIT**

Actually, looking back at this, I've oversimplified to the point of it being wrong.

`'c'` is an example of a *character constant*, which can be one *more more* characters delimited by single quotes.  The type of a character constant in C is `int`, not `char`.

Some character constants use *escape sequences* to represent non-printable characters, such as

```
'\n' - newline
'\t' - tab
'\b' - backspace
```

You can also have escape sequences with octal or hex digits:

```
'\033` - ESC using octal digits
'\x1b' - ESC using hex digits
```

Some implementations allow multibyte character constants like `'ABCD'` - the value and meaning of those constants is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful

Comment: @ShashwatGupta: please see my edit.

Comment: "Handy mnemonic - single characters use single quotes." I disagree. `char s[1] = "c"` is single character and uses double quotes. It should instead be single chars where only one char will be stored use single quotes and strings use double quotes.